Can the solution to a controlled SDE with additive noise have non full support?
Let $W$ be a standard $d$-dimensional Brownian motion. Consider the following SDE
$$dX_t = b(X_t, u_t) \, dt + dW_t$$
with initial condition $X_0 = 0$ a.s., $b: \mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ Lipschitz continuous, and $u_t$ a progressively measurable, $\mathbb R^n$ valued process with respect to the underlying Brownian motion $W$ satisfying
$$\mathbb E \left [\int_0^T b(0, u_t)^2 \, dt \right] < \infty.$$
The above condition guarantees the existence of a unique strong solution to the SDE on $[0, T]$.
Question: Does there exist at least some such $b, u$ such that $X$ does not have full support in $C[0, T]$ under the sup norm?

This seems similar to  Hormander’s theorem…

Ha, well I want kind of the opposite of the usual support theorems, where I want non-full support. @user479223

@user479223 Hm I may have a nice elementary approach, actually.

Also see Stroock Varadhan.

@user479223 According to Stroock Varadhan, there is no hope if $b$ is uncontrolled and Lipschitz continuous.

If $u$ is adapted then it is a function of $X$ right. Maybe that helps.

The SDE for the Brownian Bridge satisfies all your conditions with $b(x,u)=-xu$ and $u_t=\frac{1}{1-t}$ and does not have full support in $C_0([0,1])$.

Great example, thanks so much.

Here is an elementary solution. Let $d = n = 1$, and let $b(x, u) := u$.
Write the stopping times $\tau_n := \inf\{t \geq 0 \, | \, X_t \geq 1 - 1/n\}$, and set $u_t := -10^{10^n}$ on $\tau_n \leq t \leq \tau_{n-1}$.
Then standard estimates on drifted Brownian motion, along with Borel-Cantelli say that $\sup_{t \in [0, T]} X_t < 1$ almost surely.

Does this $u$ satisfy the bound that you required?

Good question… @m7e. This must be checked.
